# How to get two windows in one Alt + Tab?

Tags: windows, windows-10, alt-tab

I'd like to have two (or more) windows (*preferably that I can adjust the size of rather than having to split 50/50*) and attach them so that I can, use one <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to both.

**For example:** Having *Internet Explorer* and *Command Prompt* together. If this is possible, I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to do it, thank you. I am on Windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: Are you talking about doing something like this http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/multi-windows.jpg ?

Comment: What about creating different desktops and setting your desired window combinations in them?

Comment: I need same thing in linux for writing latex code in terminal vim and view the output in pdf viewer.

Answer (score 3):

Windows does not natively support this, but it is possible.

You will need to use a 2nd pc and use RDP, VNC, TeamViewer, etc... to connect to it. This desktop will then become one window that you can size and alt-tab to.

Alternatively, you can use a Virtual Machine, such as Oracle VirtualBox, install Windows into it, and run your applications in there. You can then alt-tab to that VM and view the windows like that. Running a VM does cost a lot of CPU usage, and is probably not what you want for a simple task as this.

Lastly, you can use Virtual Desktops to group windows together, and switching to a different Virtual Desktop will hide all but these windows. Windows 10 comes with its own Virtual Desktop manager, recognizable by the `[`[_]`]` icon in the taskbar next to the startmenu orb. If you Alt-Tab to one of the programs, it will show both. Alternatively you can <kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd> to navigate between desktops.

You may have to enable Virtual Desktops first. To do so, go to `start` > `Settings`>`System`>`Multi-tasking`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following keyboard shortcuts to get the behavior you want:

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> moves the current window to the left half of the screen.
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> moves the current window to the right half of the screen.
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> maximes the current window.

[image: Used Win + Left Arrow]

Haven't used [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) it but you might be able to get what you want.