# When you have two windows snapped in Windows 10 , is there a way to Alt-Tab to both of them at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, snap

In Window 10, I have two windows snapped on the right and left side of a screen. When I <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> from a full size window to the snapped windows, I need to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> once and I will see one of the snapped windows and half of the full screen windows. The second <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will allow me to bring back the other snapped window.

Is there a way (or tool) with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or something else tab) to bring back both of the snapped windows with one shortcut?

Comment: Alt-tab sets the focus to the particular window and makes it active, in the sense that input will go to it. You can't have two windows active at the same time. The closest you'll come to that is Tetsujin's suggestion of using multiple desktops.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Yes, but there is nothing that would stop it from bringing several windows to top of the Z-order, instead of only the focussed one. (Some other desktop environments had implemented this in the past, either bringing forth both "tiled" windows, or all windows of the same app, or something similar.)

Comment: How would it know? How do you force a Z-order when arranging windows on the desktop?

Comment: Windows know that the tho snapped windows are some kind of "group" it even allow to resize them at the same time. It would make sense to bring them back on top, and give the focus to the last one in focus of the two.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Such shortcuts are implemented by the window manager; knowing the layout and defining the Z-order is *literally its job.* (For example, Windows _does_ know that two side-tiled windows form a pair -- it already lets you resize them simultaneously by showing a middle divider.)

Comment: Have you look at Microsoft's PowerToy's? It has a program called Fancy Zones, which might have a function to Alt-Tab to a specific set of Windows. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install

Comment: related: [How to get two windows in one Alt + Tab?](https://superuser.com/q/1081023/241386)

Comment: I swear I was not doing guerilla marketing for windows 11.

Answer (score 54):

You can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to drop the full-size window to the *bottom* of the stack, revealing both of your tiled windows at once.

Comment: that's a nifty trick, thanks!

Comment: Oh my. How have I gone this long without knowing this keyboard shortcut? Thank you so much!!!!! :-)

Comment: @kmort [The Forgotten Hotkey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd424927(v=msdn.10))

Answer (score 43):

I'd investigate multiple desktops - then you could just switch to the desktop containing both your apps.

From [Microsoft Support - Multiple desktops in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-desktops-in-windows-10-36f52e38-5b4a-557b-2ff9-e1a60c976434)

> Multiple desktops are great for keeping unrelated, ongoing projects organized, or for quickly switching desktops before a meeting. To create multiple desktops:
>
> On the taskbar, select Task view > New desktop .
>
> Open the apps you want to use on that desktop.
>
> To switch between desktops, select Task view again.

You can then switch between desktops using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>.

[Virtual Desktops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop) in many forms are a great way of dividing up your workflow. I've been using them since the late 90s on Mac [as a 3rd party add-on at that time] & couldn't live without them. It was eventually bought from that developer & added to OS X in 2007. Windows has had it natively since Win10 [2015]. It was first used on the Amiga in 1987 and  unix X Windows, in 1989.

Comment: Nice. I've been using workspaces on Linux for more than two decades, I didn't know they've been available on windows for more than 5 years. Thanks.

Comment: @EricDuminil Third party tools have brought workspaces to Windows as far back as Windows 98 at least. Probably Windows 95.

Comment: Note that Windows 10’s implementation of multiple desktops can be a bit lacking—particularly when paired with Windows 10’s implementation of restarts for updates, which can be difficult to prevent and which never restore windows to multiple desktops after the restart (not that it accurately restores windows on a single desktop very often either). Also, I don’t know if this is the norm on other systems, but e.g. clicking a link outside of a browser opens a new tab in whichever browser window was last active—even if that browser window was on another desktop, which I find very annoying.

Comment: @KRyan The restart problem is most likely an issue (there are no persistent IDs across virtual desktops from what I remember, although there might be workarounds or new APIs been added since I last checked), but the link opening thing is simply a bug (or missing feature) in whatever browser you're using. There are ways to handle that correctly.

Comment: @EricDuminil it first appeared in Vista, but without UI support and no PR at all so only wierdos that check out whats new in WinAPI discovered it was added. And thats how I made my "own" Virtual Desktop app in 2008 (if you can call executing two built-ins an app). [Sysinternals made Desktops](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) app to showcase that cool piece of new API, so you can unlock this feature on anything Vista/2008 or newer.

Comment: @PTwr: 'Desktop objects' existed even before Vista -- I actually remember the Sysinternals tool working on Windows XP. It did have downsides, as each 'desktop' was completely isolated from the rest -- from what I remember, each desktop had to run its own explorer.exe (which then ran your "autorun" apps 4 times), you couldn't move windows between them, etc. (I think even the clipboard was separate per-desktop?) It did not really offer the same flexibility as third-party hacks.

Comment: @user1686 intriguing, sounds like some dirty Desktop/Screen HWND manipulation. New API in Vista/2008 was specifically made for that task, but without Explorer/desktop/app support it was quite cumbersome (eg. no tray icons, Chrome tab manager going nuts, the usual effects of not supported feature).

Comment: @PTwr: Yeah, that sounds exactly like the result you get with Sysinternals Desktops? No tray icons because it's a completely separate Explorer instance connected to a different desktop object... yeah, the API was made for the task, but wasn't suitable for the task. The feature in Windows 10 _doesn't_ seem to use the desktop objects API at all -- it appears to work entirely at window manager level (like it does on other OS); all processes seem to have handles to exactly the same `\Default` object, no matter which virtual desktop they are on.

Answer (score 3):

A focused, visible, and non-maximized window can be minimized quickly via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (Windows + Down Arrow).

Your most recently minimized window can be restored to its original state using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (Windows + Up Arrow).

A focused, visible, and non-maximized window can be maximized using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>. An already maximized window will experience no change.